# Origine dell'elisione dello spazio in "viceversa"

Tags: translation, history, latin

Qualcuno sa come mai la locuzione latina *vice versa* in italiano ha perso lo spazio diventando una parola unica (tra l'altro, non sono sicura che sia scorretto scriverla come due parole in italiano, presumo che in tal caso verrebbe percepita come forma latina)?

Si noti che in inglese si scrive in due parole.

Comment: Curiosamente in spagnolo è anche "viceversa".

Comment: Il processo in linguistica si chiama di "[composizione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-composte_(La_grammatica_italiana)/)", quando si forma una nuova parola dall’unione di due o più parole o parti di parole. Non so se "viceversa" abbia una sua storia particolare.

Comment: È successo lo stesso con l'espressione "et cetera" che è diventata "eccetera" in italiano ed "etcétera" in spagnolo.

Comment: ...e in “terremoto”, e negli avverbi in “-mente”...

Comment: Immagino (senza prove) che, essendo una locuzione in cui le due parole non hanno vita propria, si sia un po' alla volta affermata la scrittura come parola singola.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Viceversa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/viceversa/)" è dal latino "vice versā" o anche "versā vice".

Si tratta di un [ablativo assoluto](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ablativo/).

"Vice" è l'ablativo singolare di "vicis", "vicenda", sostantivo femminile; "versa" è il participio passato di "vertĕre", "volgere", terza coniugazione.

Quindi "vice versā" è "rigirata la faccenda".

In italiano il sintagma latino si è fuso in un elemento lessicale unico di natura avverbiale, benché raramente in passato sia rimasto in uso come locuzione avverbiale (forse solo come citazione colta in latino?).

Come osserva DaG, questo caso sembra essere molto simile agli [avverbi italiani che finiscono in "-mente"](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/avverbi-di-maniera_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/), anche questi ottenuti per fusione di sintagmi latini originariamente in ablativo assoluto ("fermamente", da "firmā mente", "con animo fermo"). Si parla qui di [univerbazione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/univerbazione_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/) per [grammaticalizzazione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/grammaticalizzazione_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/).

La mia opinione è che anche "viceversa" sia un caso di univerbazione, più che di [composizione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/composizione_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/) come avevo ritenuto inizialmente.

Citando Sabatini e Coletti, Livio Gaeta sostiene che «quanto più un’unità del genere è d’alto uso, abituale, tanto più se ne è affermata la variante grafica (e, in fondo, anche fonetica) univerbata».

Per verificare se in italiano la forma "vice versa" sia stata in passato usata, si può cercare tra i testi di [liberliber](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=lXrVU7OJHMLC8gel84CIAg&gws_rd=ssl#filter=0&q=%22vice+versa%22+site:www.liberliber.it&safe=active&start=0): si nota che alcuni testi sono effettivamente in latino, altri in francese, [in un caso](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/m/marchesa_colombi/un_matrimonio_in_provincia/pdf/un_mat_p.pdf) vi è addirittura una battutaccia ("il Vice versa", sta versando). In alcuni casi, come nella lettera di [Quirico Filopanti](http://www.classicitaliani.it/carducci/poesia/inno_satana.htm) ad Enotrio Romano (Giosuè Carducci), non si capisce se "vice versa" debba intendersi come espressione latina colta; [in alcuni casi](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/f/fiacchi/el_sgner_pirein/pdf/fiacchi_el_sgner_pirein.pdf) si potrebbe ipotizzare che sia un refuso, quando nello stesso testo normalmente si usa in forma univerbata e vi si trova un'unica occorrenza alternativa; [in altri casi ancora](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/d/della_porta/l_olimpia/pdf/l_olim_p.pdf) viene forse usata volutamente in maniera da evocare reminiscenze latine. Quindi, in conclusione, rimane il dubbio, non vi sono occorrenze in cui sia certo che l'autore non abbia intenzionalmente usato la forma latina.

Da notare anche che cercando nel sito [classicitaliani](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=lXrVU7OJHMLC8gel84CIAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22vice+versa%22+site:www.classicitaliani.it&safe=active), si trova solo la lettera di Quirico Filopanti e due documenti in francese.

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vice+versa%2Cviceversa&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1300&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cvice%20versa%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvice%20versa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVice%20versa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cviceversa%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bviceversa%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BViceversa%3B%2Cc0) comunque suggerisce che in italiano la forma di gran lunga più diffusa sia sempre stata quella univerbata. I dizionari non contemplano l'uso della variante grafica separata.

[Emilio Manzotti (Università di Ginevra)](http://www.unige.ch/lettres/roman/italien/Articles/linguistique/EmilioManzotti/ViceversaSimmetrie.pdf), in *Similarità e simmetrie tra stati di cose. Il caso di viceversa* dedica un intero saggio agli usi di "viceversa" - è molto interessante, anche se non sembra dire nulla circa il passaggio da "vice versa" a "viceversa".